# How to loop through a folder with conditional statement in Stata?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, directory, stata, local

I have a folder with a bunch of csv files and I want to loop through each file, check if a list of variables in each of the files = 0, then save the csv file as a .dta if they do not equal 0.

I'm having trouble finding online help to do this but here's what I've tried so far:

```
foreach file in `files' {
  import delimited using `file', clear
  if a & b & c & d != 0 
  save "Desktop\myfolder\`file'.dta"
}
```

when I try this though Stata tells me "*{ required r(100)*".

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `if a & b & c & d != 0` sounds like an attempt to squeeze several lines of code into one. What's the precise condition for saving a file -- that all of these variables are always non-zero in every observation? that at least one of these variables is sometimes non-zero? and so on. As written the `if` statement lacks a sequel -- which is the error detected -- and as written the statement will be at best evaluated with reference to the first observation, perhaps not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing some code from the estimable @Wouter Wakker, let's first suppose that the criterion is that a non-zero value is found somewhere in `a b c d`

```
foreach file in `files' {
    import delimited using `file', clear

    local OK = 0 

    quietly foreach v in a b c d { 
        count if `v' != 0 
        if r(N) > 0 local OK = 1 
    } 

    if `OK' save "Desktop/myfolder/`file'.dta"
 
}
```

Whatever your precise criterion, I think you need to loop over `a b c d` and (say) `count` or `summarize` according to what you want or do not want.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I think that did it.

Comment: Hi Nick, could you tell me how to edit this code so that it deletes the rows where each of those variables equals 0, and then saves the file?

Comment: `drop if a == 0 & b == 0 & c == 0 & d == 0` followed by a `save` conditional on there being anything to save.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

From `help ifcmd`:

```
Syntax

    if exp {                         or        if exp single_command
            multiple_commands
    }
```

So you can do either

```
foreach file in `files' {
    import delimited using `file', clear
    if a & b & c & d != 0 save "Desktop\myfolder\`file'.dta"
}
```

or

```
foreach file in `files' {
    import delimited using `file', clear
    if a & b & c & d != 0 {
        save "Desktop\myfolder\`file'.dta"
    }
}
```

However, I don't think your if condition does what you think it does. What you're looking for would rather be:

```
if a != 0 & b != 0 & c != 0 & d != 0
```

Comment: As commented on the question, even the last line looks only at the first observation.

Comment: You're right of course, I overlooked that